# Play 2.2.2 with Java 11

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, typesafe-activator

I have a **Play 2.2.2** project I normally run with the **activator 1.3.12**. Now I updated to **Java 11** and activator complains like:

```
The java installation you have is not up to date
activator requires at least version 1.6+, you have
version 11

Please go to http://www.java.com/getjava/ and download
a valid Java Runtime and install before running activator.
```

If I try to run the application with **sbt 1.2.4** directly I get an unresolved dependency path error

```
Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.2.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/myProject/project/plugins.sbt#L8-9) 
[warn]        +- default:myProject-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) 
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.2: not found
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to get this old project running under Java 11?

Comment: That's impossible, I suppose. SBT 1.x is only available for Play >= 2.5, the old activator (which is just a sort of SBT launcher) is not ready for Java > 8. Simply continue to use a Java 8 JRE.

Comment: And its not only Play or the activator, Play and your project has a slew of dependencies which might also not be ready for Java > 8, e.g. version checks at runtime, usage of deprecated/removed classes which would incur runtime errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of SBT, remember that SBT is an open-source build tool for Scala and Java projects, similar to Java's Maven and Ant, in this order of ideas, Scala has a minimum and maximum requirement for compatibility with Java, in this link you can find the information:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

I should make a downgrade of your java version to 10.

Good luck.