# Is Play 2.5 compatible with JDK 11?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

Play 2.5's [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Installing#Prerequisites) say

```
Play requires Java 1.8.
```

But that was long before anything above Java 8 was released. I cannot find any information about the compatibility of Play 2.5 with Java 11. Anyone have this working or knows the state? We are trying to figure out in which order we will do the migration of all our components and libraries. We're developing in Java only with sbt as build tool.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52811532/14955 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/55827115/14955

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have automated stages for Java 8 and Java 11 in their pipeline. These stages have been introduced as of 2.7.x releases, I found this by looking at the change history of .travis.yml. Although the requirements of 2.6.x and 2.7.x both state that Java SE 1.8 or higher can be used.

There are several migration guides available for upgrading from 2.5 to 2.7 if this is an option to you.

- Play 2.5 to Play 2.6 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26
- Play 2.6 to Play 2.7 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Migration27

Automation: https://travis-ci.com/playframework/playframework