# Java Play akka project migration from jdk8 to jdk11

Tags: scala, java-8, playframework, akka, java-11

I am trying to migrate the project which was built on jdk8 using play and Akka framework to jdk11. During the process, I am getting the below error. Could someone please let me know why is the error being thrown?
Below are the versions I am using:

- JDK-11
- SCala 2.12.8
- Play 2.6.7
- Akka 2.5.13

Exception:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a version: 11
    at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.parts$1(Properties.scala:176)
    at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.isJavaAtLeast(Properties.scala:180)
    at scala.util.Properties$.isJavaAtLeast(Properties.scala:16)
    at play.dev.filewatch.FileWatchService$$anon$1.delegate$lzycompute(FileWatchService.scala:68)
    at play.dev.filewatch.FileWatchService$$anon$1.delegate(FileWatchService.scala:66)
    at play.dev.filewatch.FileWatchService$$anon$1.watch(FileWatchService.scala:79)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader.<init>(Reloader.scala:358)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.reloader$lzycompute$1(Reloader.scala:219)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$reloader$1(Reloader.scala:219)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:229)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:79)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:79)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:102)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:65)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a version: 11
```

Comment: What is your sbt version? JDK 11 support requires minimum sbt version 1.1.0, or 0.13.17 in the 0.13.x series.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . im using sbt 1.2.8

Comment: I see Scala has a "JDK compatibility page", maybe that is useful: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Comment: I followed the above link and added compatible version of scala . no luck it is throwing the same error when running the command "sbt run".

Answer (score 0):

https://www.lightbend.com/blog/roadmap-revealed-for-play-2.8-and-lagom-1.6

> Java 11
>   At this point, Play mostly supports Java 11. All the modules and samples are already being tested using Java; we even have Play itself building with Java 11, there is only a know issue we need to solve, related to ssl-config.

According to the link above, Play will officially support Java 11 since 2.8.